# How to include Service from library in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I am including a libary in my android app. In this library there is a service call TimeService. I have no issues including this service in my MainActivity with import com.example.mylibrary;

But of course every service also have to be included in AndroidManifest.xml.

There I write

```
    <service
        android:name=".TimeService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

But now it says TimeService cannot be resolved. Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include it with the fully qualified name.

```xml
<service android:name="com.example.library.TimeService"/>
```

Comment: ok. Do you know why on a normal service you always need this dot infront the Service name. for example. <service android:name=".MyService"/>

Comment: because in the manifes tag, you declare the property `package`. That tells the compiler what is the base package of your project.